# find the row index while selecting values in the dropdown list inside the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown list in every row whereas the default value is No. When I change the dropdown value of a particular row I need to fetch the row index. I tried this javacsript function,

```
function selectedExcludedoption() {
   var selectedExcludeoption = $('#riexclusion option:selected').text().trim();
   if (selectedExcludeoption == "Yes") {
       revisedvalue = $('tbody#riDecisionvalues td:eq(4)').text("0.00");
   }
   else {
       revisedvalue = $('tbody#riDecisionvalues  td:eq(4)').text();
   }
}
```

my table html code

```
<div id="ridecisiontable">
    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="ritable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 107px; margin-right: -5px;" class="text-left">Exclude</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: ridecisionGroups" id="riDecisionvalues">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 107px;margin-right: -5px;">
                    <div class="col-sm-5" style="margin-right: -15px;">
                        <select class="form-control text-right excluded" id="riexclusion" onchange="selectedExcludedoption()">
                            <option value="No">No</option>
                            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

How to get the particular row index value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass this object in javascript function

```
<select class="form-control text-right excluded" id="riexclusion" onchange="selectedExcludedoption(this)">
  <option value="No">No</option>
  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
```

and modify the function

```
function selectedExcludedoption(selectBox)
        {            
           var rowIndex = $(selectBox).closest('tr').index();
            alert(rowIndex);
            var selectedExcludeoption = $('#riexclusion option:selected').text().trim();
            if (selectedExcludeoption == "Yes")
            {
                revisedvalue= $('tbody#riDecisionvalues td:eq(4)').text("0.00");

            }
            else {
                revisedvalue= $('tbody#riDecisionvalues  td:eq(4)').text();

            }
        }
```

Comment: no, selectBox is the object instance of select box for which function called

Answer (score 1):

you need to find the closest `tr`

```
<select class="form-control text-right excluded" id="riexclusion" onchange="selectedExcludedoption(this)">
                                                    <option value="No">No</option>
                                                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                                                </select>
```

write this inside `selectedExcludedoption`

```
function selectedExcludedoption(obj){

  var rowIndex=$(obj).closest('tr').index();

    rowIndex=rowIndex-1; //exclude thead row.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you selected row index

```
$("#ritable tr select").live('change', function(e){
   alert($(this).closest('td').parent()[0].sectionRowIndex);
});
```